# New row not inserted in ascending order - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I have recently created a new table with certain data - it will download data once every day and will post them in order
but now something strange happened . I can not find anything wrong in my sql syntax in php and I do the same for my other tables - works perfect!!!.
I have , as usual, a primary key that is unique and is incremented for each new value . **But now - suddenly - day three suddenly database**
 **store this value above the last value**

I do not understand what is wrong . I wonder if its how the server is configurated or something wrong in my syntax? As I mentioned above - my other tables works and implements the same syntax . What I have seen
on various forums is that one NEVER is guaranteed that data is stored in order **if** you do not specify this . But I can not find any syntax that combines INSERT INTO and ORDER BY

And as I said - I have a lot of other tables which operate under basically the same code and stores the data I want - in ascending order.

I attach a picture to show . One can see that the server put the new row in between the last and first -

So my question

1- why is this happening?
2 How could I fix this problem.

Could one somehow comine the INSERT INTO syntax and ORDER BY???

```
  $query = "insert into table (null, '$date', '$value1', '$value2');
```

[image] you can se that the last row is stored in between

Comment: You should never make any assumptions about the ordering of rows in a SQL database: if order is important, then you need to explicitly indicate this with an ORDER BY in your SELECT statements. ORDER BY does not apply to INSERTs, because it's the databases job simply to store the data you requested, and your job to retrieve that data in an order that you stipulate only on SELECTion

Comment: @Mark Baker Ok thanks! - but only in the select statement? I would likte to put the new data last in the table (asc. order) from the very beginning.

Comment: The whole point of databases is that the database knows best how to store the data; you know how you like to __see it__ ordered, but to __see it__ you need to SELECT it, therefore ORDER BY is associated with SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost answered your own question.

> What I have seen on various forums is that one is NEVER guaranteed that data is stored in order

This is true. If you need to retrieve the data back out of your database in a specific order, then you should use an `ORDER BY` as you `SELECT` the data.